# Setting TextView text color in a listview gives color to random textviews while scrolling?

Tags: android, listview

Everything works fine till I dont scroll.As soon as I scroll down other TextView get the color randomly.Here is my code.

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //  ViewHolder holder = null;
          View row = convertView;
          if(row==null){
           LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
           row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.prices_list, parent, false);
          }




         item = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         item.setText(items[position]);
         price = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         price.setText(prices[position]);         
         cprice=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         cprice.setTag(position);
         cprice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
        TextView tv1=(TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2=(TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        create(tv2.getText().toString(),tv2,tv1.getText().toString(),position);

            }
        });





          return row;
         }


        }
create function:
public void create(String price, final TextView tv1,final String item,final int position)
    {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Update Prices");
    builder.setMessage("Current Price "+price);

     // Use an EditText view to get user input.
     final EditText input = new EditText(this);

     builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
             uvalue = input.getText().toString();

             tv1.setText(uvalue);

            item_value[count]=uvalue;
            prices[position]=uvalue;
            item_name[count]=item;
            updated[count]=tv1;

             DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                dbAdapter.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            dbAdapter.openDataBase();
            try {
                String query = "UPDATE Prices SET Price="+item_value[count]+" where Item_Name='"+item_name[count]+"'";
            Log.i("TAG","Query executed");
            Cursor c = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDB(query, null);

            ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Price", item_value[count]);
            Log.i("TAG","value to be updated is"+item_value[count]);
            Log.i("TAG","Item  to be updated is"+item_name[count]);
        boolean c1= dbAdapter.updateRecordInDB("Prices", cv, "Item_Name='"+item_name[count]+"'", null);
            count++;
            if(c1)
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);


                }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dbAdapter.close();


        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
        });
    builder.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reset TextView color in onCreateView method

```
tv1.setColor(Color.Black)
```

will make every ceil black except clicked(they will be yellow)

This all happens because ceils in ListView are reused.

**UPD:**

```
price = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         price.setText(prices[position]);        


if (itemShouldBeYellow(position)){
    price.setColor(Color.Yellow); 
} else {
    price.setColor(Color.Black); 
}
```

Comment: how to use onCreateView method?

Comment: please help to fix this problem of random textview taking yellow color on scrolling??

Comment: Tried this..but now all the textvieew become black including the one which is to made yelloww??

Comment: store somewhere which items should be yellow and use it in itemShouldBeYellow(int) method

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem may be this line:

```
updated[count]=tv1;
```

can you verify that all of the textviews that are getting changed to yellow are populated from the updated array?

Comment: I removed this line of code as it was of no use...Still random texviews get yellow color on scrolling??